# seaborn catplot - marker style

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm using `sns.catplot()` to visualize data and understand a dependencies.

There is `col`, `row`, `hue` for differenciation between categories. But I cannot find out if there is also a keyword to differentiate additionally by **marker styles**.

Comment: I don't believe so. Marker styles are not applicable to all of the plot types that `catplot` can produce (e.g. barplot or violinplot). It makes sense to me that there is no inbuilt differentiation based on marker style.